# Angular website images are there but they don't show up if the window is maximized

Tags: angular

So the problem is quite straightforward, if i open my website directly through a link the images load properly, if i navigate through the website while it is maximized, the extra images for a page which are listed in a wrapping flexbox don't show up unless i resize the window or move it.

If i navigate while not maximized everything shows up properly.

I built a website using the @angular/ssr stuff because i need statically generated websites for github pages. The problem is the main images show up, only the extra images which are held in an array of strings for their respective paths don't, and only if the window is maximized.

i have no idea what to try, i cannot check the developer console or element inspector coz they show up if i have it opened.

the images are inside this div

```js
<div *ngIf="LoadedProject?.imagepatharray" class="HeaderText">Overview Images</div>
    <div *ngIf="LoadedProject?.imagepatharray" class="ImagesContainer">
        <img class="ImgDiv" *ngFor="let path of LoadedProject!.imagepatharray" src="{{path}}">        
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the content to wrap, just use `display: flex` on the elements so the change will be

```
<div *ngIf="LoadedProject?.imagepatharray" class="HeaderText">Overview Images</div>
<div *ngIf="LoadedProject?.imagepatharray" class="ImagesContainer" style="display: flex">
    <img class="ImgDiv" *ngFor="let path of LoadedProject!.imagepatharray" src="{{path}}">        
</div>
```